# How can I get width and height of an android dialog programatically

Tags: android

This is how I set the width and height of the dialog

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(720, 120);
```

Is there a way to get the width and height as I am seeing it changed but want to get the actual values before I change the values?

Comment: When are you changing the width and height values of your Dialog?